# Facebook Sharer does not retrieve OG property correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have the following line on my  tag.

```
<?php
echo "<meta property='og:title' content='".$metaTitle."'>";
echo "<meta property='og:type' content='".$metaType."'>";
echo "<meta property='og:url' content='".$metaURL."'>";
echo "<meta property='og:image' content='".$metaImage."'>";
echo "<meta property='og:site_name' content='Gellies World'>";
echo "<meta property='og:description' content='".$metaDescription."'>";
?>
```

When i view the source code, it prints correctly (although it is printed in one line altogether).

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Ka-Ching! Sound of the Casino slot machine~!'><meta property='og:type' content='article'><meta property='og:url' content='http://gelliesworld.com/library/read/31'><meta property='og:image' content='http://gelliesworld.com/users/library/poster/images_thumb.jpeg'><meta property='og:site_name' content='Gellies World'><meta property='og:description' content='A group of Japanese lawmakers are close to hitting the jackpot in their bid to legalise casinos, betting the revenue bonanza could challenge Macau for'>
```

How ever, when i debug the url using FB debugger it says that i have errors that must be fixed:

1. Meta Tags In Body

And some warnings

1. Inferred Property

And when i see the scraped URL, the source code does not appear similar to what i have when i right-click and view source

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
<meta property="og:title" content="&lt;div style=" border:1px solid>
</head>
<body>
<p>"&gt;
```

and so on.....

I am using CodeIgniter, and have 3 views namely (header, the_content, and footer). Can anyone point out what seems to be the problem?

Comment: You adding meta tags in body tag which is incorrect it must reside into the head tag.

Comment: @Rikesh that is the problem that i am facing, according to FB (scrapped URL) it sees all the meta tags outside the head tag. Where when i right-click & view source everything placed neatly within the head tag.

Comment: It seems that something is breaking when you adding content to your meta. May be because of quotes in it.

Comment: @Rikesh Thx for the reply, it seems that i was not careful. It turns out that the page which is requested by facebook is protected (i.e. user must login first). After i disable this feature it works as expected.